# PyDev doesn't import

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

by some reason PyDev does not recognise some of the basic objects from the standard "turtle" library and highlights them with red as undefined.
For example in the below code the color(), forward() etc are not recognized:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

But when I run the program from Eclipse it actually works. The import of the "turtle" library not causing errors and I can see some prompts in the PyDev editor but not for the functions.
I've tried 2.7 and 3.4 but the issue is same.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Have you tried `from turtle import color, forward, left, begin_fill, end_fill`?

Comment: yes, I have. It doesn't work this way as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `turtle` to the `forced builtins` as explained in the `Getting Started Manual`?

-- search for `forced builtins` in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for more information.